# Searching for shortest slice in an array with all unique values, how to do this in optimal way?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, unique, slice, shortest

I have an array that contains N elements, which values are in 0 <= value < N range and can be discontinuous. For this array I need to find a slice which will contain all unique values and at the same time it will be the shortest slice that will meet the above criterion.

An example, for array {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 8, 1, 8} with 5 unique values {1, 2, 3, 4, 8} we are talking about slice {2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 8} with length 6.

Is there an optimal way to do this? As for now I've naive implementation that has far too high complexity (nested loops). I've tried to come up with an idea for an algorithm to do this in an optimal way but sadly to no avail. As for now I've tried to come up with something that will make use of occurrences for each unique value when looping through array, but still my mind is not clear enough. Any ideas are welcome, this problem is troubling me for a long time. :) Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: The simplest solution appears to involve two passes through the list. One from the left and one from the right. Alternatively, one to prepare the list of unique elements and one to find the slice.

Comment: I think you want slice with all possible values.

Answer (score 0):

The first run collects possible values and creates a map with pairs `(value; counter = 0)`. Let `N`is map size

For the second run prepare two indexes - `left` and `right`, and `ActiveCnt`.

Move `right`, updating map counters. When you update zero counter, increment `ActiveCnt`. When `ActiveCnt` becomes equal to `N`, stop.

Now move `left`, decrementing map counters. When some counter becomes zero, get difference between `right` and `left`, compare it with current `MinLength`, then decrement `ActiveCnt`. Continue with `right` index and so on.